# Set zoom-dependent hash pattern to Polygon in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'd like to set hash pattern to Polygone, which adjusts on zoom in/out. So when I zoom out, gradient texture zooms out.

How to achieve that?

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far ?

Comment: Working example with zoom-INdependent pattern: https://jsfiddle.net/nt6ae1Ld/11/